# cvat wont load uploaded images

Tags: cvat

Im using cvat locally through the docker image. Everything worked fine so far. I could upload images from my local storage, upload annotations, change annotations and also export those again.

Now on my second dataset, I could upload images without problems, but then the wont load within cvat. I started to get the error message "Could not receive image data. Error: Request failed with status code 502"

After restarting the Container multiple times and restarting my PC, it finally worked, however only for the first 72 images and now I get the same error.

Output in Browsers Console:

```
:8080/api/user-agreements?org=:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)
cvat-app.tsx:375 Error: Request failed with status code 502. "<html>\r\n<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->\r\n".
e @ cvat-app.tsx:375
cvat-app.tsx:375 Error: Request failed with status code 502.
e @ cvat-app.tsx:375
cvat-app.tsx:375 Error: Request failed with status code 502.
e @ cvat-app.tsx:375
showErrors @ cvat-app.tsx:387
componentDidUpdate @ cvat-app.tsx:286
ii @ react-dom.production.min.js:212
gs @ react-dom.production.min.js:255
n.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:19
Ga @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
As @ react-dom.production.min.js:248
os @ react-dom.production.min.js:239
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
n.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:19
Ga @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
qa @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
Za @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
as @ react-dom.production.min.js:240
notify @ Subscription.js:16
notifyNestedSubs @ Subscription.js:88
a @ Subscription.js:93
g @ redux.js:296
(anonymous) @ redux-logger.es.js:832
(anonymous) @ index.js:20
onGetDataFailed @ canvas-wrapper.tsx:333
(anonymous) @ canvas-wrapper.tsx:606
(anonymous) @ canvasView.ts:114
notify @ canvasView.ts:1811
notify @ master.ts:27
(anonymous) @ canvasModel.ts:610
Promise.catch (async)
setup @ canvasModel.ts:602
setup @ canvas.ts:77
updateCanvas @ canvas-wrapper.tsx:982
componentDidUpdate @ canvas-wrapper.tsx:533
ii @ react-dom.production.min.js:212
gs @ react-dom.production.min.js:255
n.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:19
Ga @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
As @ react-dom.production.min.js:248
os @ react-dom.production.min.js:239
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
n.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:19
Ga @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
qa @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
Za @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
as @ react-dom.production.min.js:240
notify @ Subscription.js:16
notifyNestedSubs @ Subscription.js:88
a @ Subscription.js:93
g @ redux.js:296
(anonymous) @ redux-logger.es.js:832
(anonymous) @ index.js:20
dispatch @ redux.js:691
(anonymous) @ annotation-actions.ts:695
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ index.js:16
onChangeFrame @ top-bar.tsx:154
changeFrame @ top-bar.tsx:619
(anonymous) @ top-bar.tsx:388
await in (anonymous) (async)
NEXT_FRAME @ top-bar.tsx:702
u @ mousetrap.js:616
n._handleKey @ mousetrap.js:677
v.handleKey @ mousetrap.js:1008
d @ mousetrap.js:737
Show 42 more frames
Show less
cvat-app.tsx:375 Error: Request failed with status code 502.
e @ cvat-app.tsx:375
showErrors @ cvat-app.tsx:387
componentDidUpdate @ cvat-app.tsx:286
ii @ react-dom.production.min.js:212
gs @ react-dom.production.min.js:255
n.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:19
Ga @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
As @ react-dom.production.min.js:248
os @ react-dom.production.min.js:239
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
n.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:19
Ga @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
qa @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
Za @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
as @ react-dom.production.min.js:240
notify @ Subscription.js:16
notifyNestedSubs @ Subscription.js:88
a @ Subscription.js:93
g @ redux.js:296
(anonymous) @ redux-logger.es.js:832
(anonymous) @ index.js:20
onGetDataFailed @ canvas-wrapper.tsx:333
(anonymous) @ canvas-wrapper.tsx:606
(anonymous) @ canvasView.ts:114
notify @ canvasView.ts:1811
notify @ master.ts:27
(anonymous) @ canvasModel.ts:610
Promise.catch (async)
setup @ canvasModel.ts:602
setup @ canvas.ts:77
updateCanvas @ canvas-wrapper.tsx:982
componentDidUpdate @ canvas-wrapper.tsx:533
ii @ react-dom.production.min.js:212
gs @ react-dom.production.min.js:255
n.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:19
Ga @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
As @ react-dom.production.min.js:248
os @ react-dom.production.min.js:239
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
n.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:19
Ga @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
qa @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
Za @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
as @ react-dom.production.min.js:240
notify @ Subscription.js:16
notifyNestedSubs @ Subscription.js:88
a @ Subscription.js:93
g @ redux.js:296
(anonymous) @ redux-logger.es.js:832
(anonymous) @ index.js:20
dispatch @ redux.js:691
(anonymous) @ annotation-actions.ts:695
await in (anonymous) (async)
(anonymous) @ index.js:16
onChangeFrame @ top-bar.tsx:154
changeFrame @ top-bar.tsx:619
(anonymous) @ top-bar.tsx:388
await in (anonymous) (async)
i @ react-dom.production.min.js:14
p @ react-dom.production.min.js:14
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:14
g @ react-dom.production.min.js:15
rn @ react-dom.production.min.js:52
on @ react-dom.production.min.js:51
ln @ react-dom.production.min.js:52
pn @ react-dom.production.min.js:56
L @ react-dom.production.min.js:287
U @ react-dom.production.min.js:19
Jn @ react-dom.production.min.js:70
Xn @ react-dom.production.min.js:69
n.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:19
Ga @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
j @ react-dom.production.min.js:287
qn @ react-dom.production.min.js:68
Show 54 more frames
Show less
```

I tried restarting the Container and device. I found no answer on here.